# Omnetpp Config for router in ned

Tags: omnet++

I have a network of around 20 nodes. Each node is a compund module which has a StandardHost based node and an OSPFRouter in it(where the router is connected to module internally ). All these nodes are connected in a random order. Now for the routers in each module I am writing a config file. So I have a config file with distinct network address for each node(each node represents a different area). Now writing such config file is getting very lengthy. for example check the code below:

```
config = xml("<config>"+
                                "<interface among='sic0.*' address='192.168.21.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"+

                                "<interface among='sic1.*' address='192.168.22.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"+

                                "<interface among='sic3.*' address='192.168.23.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"+

                                "<interface among='sic4.*' address='192.168.24.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"+
.
.
.
.
"<route hosts='sic*.R*' destination='*' netmask='0.0.0.0' interface='eth0' />"+
                                "</config>");
```

As i am having 20 nodes this file becomes very long.
So I wanted to know if there a way to have abstraction and make the xml config parameter to be smaller?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if OMNeT++ provides a buit-in mechanism to address such a case. However what I would do is, create a script which would generate the whole file based on parameters I pass to it.

I would use Python as it is the easiest and quickest to grasp (at least for me).

Your `config` file does not seem to be very complicated -- at least based on what you have posted. All you have to do is increment a variable: `192.168.variable.x` and let the script write the rest of the file.